# Need help in getting my combination of strings from treeview column into textbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get the text inside my Address column which contains a combination of string fetched from mysql into the tkinter text box but it returns error. Can anyone help me?

fetching from sql

```
_sql = "SELECT * FROM customers"
_val = None
custs = sql.fetchAll(_sql,_val)
if custs != None:
    for i, (id,name,address1,address2,address3,address4,phone,email,birthdate) in enumerate(custs, start=1):
        listBox.insert("","end",values=(id,name,address1+", "+address2+", "+address3+", "+address4,phone,email,birthdate))
```

my treeview code:

```
cols=('ID','Name','Address','Phone','Email','Birthdate')
listBox=ttk.Treeview(listFrame, columns=cols, show='headings',height=36)
for col in cols:
listBox.heading(col, text=col)
listBox.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2)
listBox.column(col,minwidth=0,width=262,stretch=NO,anchor=CENTER)
listBox.place(x=30,y=173)
listBox.bind('<Double-Button-1>',self.selectCust)
```

textbox code:

```
e2=Text(listFrame,fg="#18191b",bg="#fbb913",width=20,borderwidth=0,highlightthickness=0,height=5,wrap=WORD)
e2.place(x=100,y=52)
```

trying to insert strings from address column to textbox:

```
e2.insert(0,sel['Address'])
```

error output:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "e:\AMAR\ADBMS\db.py", line 121, in selectCust
    e2.insert(0,sel['Address'])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3743, in insert
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index, chars) + args)
_tkinter.TclError: bad text index "0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter `Text` objects accept indexes in the form `"<line>.<character>"`, so the first line, first character would be represented as `"1.0"`. The second line, first character would be `"2.0"`, the fourth line, ninth character would be `"4.8"` and so on.

In this case, you could change the problem line to:

```py
e2.insert('1.0', sel['Address'])
```

[TkDocs Text widget](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html)